# Performance hit after migrating to sql 2017 from 2012 for Table-valued-functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

Migrated from 2012 to 2017 one month ago (testing seem to go ok but not rigorous testing). After one month, I have noticed that Table value functions that start with a series of Commmon table expressions take very long to execute or not at all. I am ok with re-writing the code (3rd party app along with our own custom code side-by-side... ouch). What I noticed today is that a query runs fine in SQL2012 server ( I still have access to it) and goes out to lunch entirely on the SQL2017. I thought this might happen and kept compatibility settings for all dbs. Has anyone run into this?

I have played around with 9481 but as I understand, with Comp Level 110, this should not even be a problem. Are there any other server settings I can set to force it to behave as it has then tackle the problems (there are a lot) one-by-one.

Also, because these tvf tables are reused and referenced everywhere, its important that they remain as such. I cannot rearrange the furniture too much. The developers have leveraged both TVF and CTE.

Migrated from 2012 to 2017 one month ago, kept Compatibility the same. Pattern has developed whereby queries:

```
Select t1.Col1
t1.Col2,t2.Col8,
tvfTable1.Col10, etc...
FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.key=t2.foreignkey
CROSS APPLY (t1.Col1,t2,col4,0,1,2,3) tvfTable1
```

the TVF's all seem to start with:

```
...
AS RETURN (
WITH CTE1 AS (query),
CTE2 AS (query referencing CTE1)
...
SELECT MANYColumns
FROM MANYTABLES JOIN CTE4 on mt.key=cte4.key
```

Comment: A good start when diagnosing differences is always to get execution plans for one execution vs. another. If the query will not return at all on 2017, you can at least get an estimated execution plan that will show if the basic approach is the same (it likely will not be). Keeping the compatibility level will not *completely* make the optimizer behave the same as it did in 2012; the only guaranteed way to get exactly the same behavior is to not upgrade (which is undesirable for other reasons, of course...)

Comment: Thank you. Yea, I really dont want to analyze plans. Its a mess. Tvf tables referencing tvf... about 3 or more deep before I get to a base-table. The plans are impossible to read. I know I can rewrite the queries to be faster, but I cannot rewrite every one. I need a silver bullet.

Comment: You're unlikely to get one, I'm afraid. In particular, there is no "please behave exactly as this other server I've got over here" trace flag. You should at least analyze *one* instance of *one* query to compare between 2012 and 2017 to get an idea of what the actual problem is -- cardinality estimates? New statistics? Different use of parallelism? Some things may admit actual fixes/tweaks on the server level, some may not. You don't have to analyze the plans yourself -- get them, [paste them](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), and see if there are smart people here that can.

Comment: First thing I'd always check: see if you have the latest SP/CU installed. Next, what Jeroen is suggesting.

Comment: Table valued functions and CTEs have never been known to be good for performance. Inline table valued functions may be a bit better, but that all depends on what they are returning.

Comment: Oh, and there's one more cheap and obvious thing to try -- what if you *don't* keep the compat level and allow the new optimizer to stretch its legs? In other words, bump the compat level to 140 and see if the situation improves. Obviously, you might want to [check](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) if there's anything in your database that might break -- the breaking changes aren't many, but there are some.

Comment: The great majority of the tvf are inline. I think the key here is that there seems to be this combustion between using the CTE within the TVF code. The same code runs "ok" in 2012 - times out in 2017 with 110 comp. mode. So, compatibility mode only gets you so far once you migrate, I guess. 
Jeroen - I did do that with one of the databases and it didnt effect the change. But I will try on the main production db on test. Luckily, I have a test environment that is close to production to play around with. I will play around with that.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jaroen has already commented, any performance problem issue can be best advised when at the minimum:

1. Underlying table data volume information
2. Underlying table and index structure
3. Execution Plan screenshot or details are provided.

**With the limited details provided**, here are a few things you can try:

1. While running the query, please check for waits stats in in the server by
   querying at dmvs: sys.dm_os_wait_stats and sys.dm_tran_locks. Please
   check whether the wait is due to CXPACKET (waits due to other
   parallel processes) or PAGEIOLATCH (Reading from Disk than RAM) or
   locks. It is the starting point of the investigation which will give
   you the root cause and you can then take appropriate measure
   accordingly.
2. Please check whether statistics are updated in your new server. If not,
   please update statistics of the underlying tables (try with FULLSCAN
   if possible if you have not updated statistics since your migration
   to the new server)
3. Please make sure that the structure (including indexes) and
   volume of underlying tables in both the servers are the same and no
   accidents happened during server migration.
4. Could you make sure if your MAXDOP configuration are optimized with
   respect to the number of logical processors you have in your new
   server?
5. I would also want to ask you the difference in RAM between the 2
   servers. Could you check the 'Available RAM' in each server
   when you are executing the same query?
6. Ideally, if possible I would suggest you to move to compatibility
   level 2017 as soon as possible, because for a long time,
   compatibility level only influenced the way T-SQL gets interpreted
   and didn’t have to do anything with performance. But Starting from
   SQL Server 2014, we get the new cardinality estimates and other
   improvements on how the execution plans are built. And by changing
   that, we suddenly get a different query plan for many queries which
   can perform much faster than the older execution plans which
   compatibility level 2012 or older version was generating. Usually
   during SQL Server upgrade it is advised that initially one should
   keep the original compatibility level. Once it runs fine for 1-2
   weeks after the server upgrade, we can set the compatibility level
   of the SQL Server to the latest version in the dev server and test
   if everything is working fine. After that, the compatibility level
   can be upgraded to the latest version in production environment.
7. Here is an article on performance of TVFs across different versions
   of SQL Server:
   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5728/sql-server-multi-statement-table-value-function-mtvfs-performance-difference-between-versions/

Comment: Thank you san. I think part of the problem is its a third-party software. But this reminds me that I need to revisit the tiered storage question. This is a virtual machine at a provider. I have no real server admin to talk to as I have in other jobs. But I was told that we have wall to wall SSD disks. So, I took a chance and put data and log on the same volume. I may rethink that. I have some perfmon counters running for AVG Disk queue length and I only see queueing at backup times. But I may revisit that tomorrow. I can fairly quickly get a separate volume for log and move them there

Comment: @Bukester let me know how it goes. I would also be interested to know about your findings on item #1, #2, #3 above. And please feel free to upvote the answer if it helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. It seems I made a mistake in that I ALREADY had Compatibility Level at 140 when I thought it was 110. So, my original confusion was how could the behaviour be so bad at the old level. I moved it back down to 110 and things are predictable now. It was never great with the tvf but at 140, its terrible. We have a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue when running in MSSQL 2016, when the compatibility level was updated to "SQL Server 2016 (130)" and the performance of multi-statement TVFs went into the dumper.  This situation can be rectified via either of the following:

1. Set compatibility level back to "SQL Server 2012 (110)"
2. Leave compatibility level at 130, but set "Legacy Cardinality Extimation" to "ON"